# zabbix vfs.file.regmatch regex

Tags: regex, monitoring, zabbix

I'm new to zabbix. I need to monitor the log file and create a warning if its content doesn't meet the following:

```
{ "10.0.0.1": "0" }
```

I tried to use vfs.file.regmatch for this and with following regexes:

```
vfs.file.regmatch[/tmp/test72.log,'\{ \"10\.0\.0\.1\"\: \"0\" \}']
vfs.file.regmatch[/tmp/test72.log,‘{ "10.0.0.1": "0"}’]
```

But all of them returns 0 (False), when I check in zabbix web interface, but trying to run in shell I get the following (expected result):

```
zabbix_agentd -t vfs.file.regmatch[/tmp/test72.log,'{ "10.0.0.1": "0" }']
vfs.file.regmatch[/tmp/test72.log,{ "10.0.0.1": "0" }] [u|1]
```

Have I missed some escape characters?

ALso, my Zabbix server and agents versions are 3.4.15.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `vfs.file.regmatch[/tmp/test72.log,"\{ \"10\.0\.0\.1\": \"0\" \}"]`

Comment: updating both agent and server would be a good idea, too